# How to map single object instead of IEnumerable in LinQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var result = this._databaseContext.MyCustomers.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(p => p.customerActive.HasValue && p.customerActive.Value)
                .Include(p => p.MailAddress)
                .Select(c => new CustomerModel
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Address = c.MailAddress
                 }
```

I want to convert 'MailAddress' object to 'Address' object. I have checked the 'select' method from Linq but it only allow mapping of object from IEnumerable.

Comment: have you tried `new Address() { ... }`

Comment: If you're sure that there is a single one (or none), you could apply `FirstOrDefault` at the end

Comment: why did you write `.Include()`, but dont't use it?

Comment: @3per It is  .Include(p => p.MailAddress) changed

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = this._databaseContext.MyCustomers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.customerActive.HasValue && p.customerActive.Value)
    .Include(p => p.MailAddress)
    .Select(c => new CustomerModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Name = c.Name,
        Address = c.MailAddress
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your CustomerModel Address property and MyCustomer MailAddress property is same class then you can use MailAddress.FirstOrDefault() as shown below.

```
 var result = this._databaseContext.MyCustomers.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(p => p.customerActive.HasValue && p.customerActive.Value)
            .Include(p => p.MailAddress)
            .Select(c => new CustomerModel()
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
                Address = c.MailAddress.FirstOrDefault()
             });
```

If you want to project the MailAddress to different class like AddressModel use the below query.

```
   var result = this._databaseContext.MyCustomers.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(p => p.customerActive.HasValue && p.customerActive.Value)
            .Include(p => p.MailAddress)
            .Select(c => new CustomerModel()
            {
                Id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
                Address = c.MailAddress
                            .Select(ad=> new AddressModel() 
                                     {Place= ad.Place, PinCode = a d.PinCode}).FirstOrDefault()});
```

Answer (score 0):

### most LINQ methods return IEnumerable

You know that an `IEnumerable<...>` (and `IQueryable<...>`) represents the potential to access a sequence of similar elements one by one. It does not represent this sequence itself, like a List or array does.

If you investigate `IEnumerable<...>`, you can see that getting the elements is done using `GetEnumerator`, and repeatedly call MoveNext() / Current until you've processed the elements that you need.

```
IEnumerable<CustomerModel> customers = ...
IEnumerator<CustomerModel> customerEnumerator = customers.GetEnumerator();
while (customerEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    // There is next element in the sequence
    CustomerModel nextElementToProcess = customerEnumerator.Current();
    Process(nextElementToProcess);
}
```

This is a lot of code, hence `foreach` was invented. Foreach does what you see above: it get's the enumerator, and creates a `while(enumerator.MoveNext())`.

If you look closely at LINQ methods, you'll see that there are two kinds of LINQ methods: those that return `IEnumerable<...>` (or `IQueryable<...>`) and the others. Methods from the first group return "the potential to get the elements one by one", as described above, the others return elements: sometimes a sequence like a list / array, sometimes other elements like Count.

The descriptions of methods from the first group all mention that they use *deferred execution*. That means: it is not the sequence itself, it is the potential to get the elements. Once you `GetEnumerator()` and `MoveNext()` the code is executed.

If you read the above, you'll know by know, that your query is not executed yet. It represents the potential to get the elements. You need a method from the second group, or foreach to execute the query.

Apparently you expect zero or one element. In that case your last method can be `FirstOrDefault()`. Even if you expect more elements, but you are only interested in the first one, you can use `FirstOrDefault()`.

So when concatenating LINQ methods, you should always only concatenate elements that return `IEnumerable<...>`. Only the last one should be a method from the second group: `ToList()`, `Count()`, `Any()`, etc.

### Back to your problem

Apparently you have a table of Customers and a table of EmailAddresses. There seems to be a one-to-many relationship between Customers and EmailAddresses: Every Customer has zero or one EmailAddresses, every EmailAddress belongs to exactly one Customer, namely the Customer that the foreign key refers to.

You seem to want several properties of all Active customers, including their First EmailAddress, or null if this Customer doesn't have an EmailAddress.

You were right: to select one or more Properties of a class, use `Select`. The result is a sequence. You are only interested in the first element of this sequence: Add `FirstOrDefault()`

> When using entity framework, always use Select, and select only the properties that you plan to use. Only use `Include` if you plan to change / update the Included data.

The reason is, that Include will fetch all properties, inclusive the properties that youp don't plan to use, or the ones that you know the value of. Every EmailAddress of Customer [10] has a foreign key CustomerId with a value 10. So if you fetch Customer [10] with his EmailAddresses, you already know what the value of `EmailAddress.CustomerId` would be.

> I want to convert 'MailAddress' object to 'Address' object.

```
var result = this._databaseContext.MyCustomers.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(customer => customer.customerActive.HasValue && customer.customerActive.Value)
    .Select(customer => new CustomerModel
    {
        Id = customer.Id,
        Name = customer.Name,
        Address = customer.MailAddresses.FirstOrDefault(),
    })

    // result is the potential to fetch the elements. To actually fetch all these Customers add:
    .ToList();
```

It might be that Customer.MailAddresses contains a different type that CustomerModel.Address, in that case use an extra Select.

```
.Select(customer => new CustomerModel
{
    ...
    Address = customer.MailAddresses.Select(mailAddress =>
          ... // create a value that can be assigned to CustomerModel.Address
          )
          .FirstOrDefault(),
})
.ToList();
```